# convert notebook generated HTML snippet to LaTeX and PDF

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In my notebooks I sometimes have

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
...
display(HTML('<h3>The %s is important!</h3>'%question_of_the_day))
...
```

but when I later convert the notebook to `.pdf` (with the intermediate step of a LaTeX file) what I get in the `.pdf` is just

> `<IPython.core.display.HTML object>`

My question is, is it possible to convince `jupyter nbconvert --to pdf ...` (and ultimately to convince `pandoc`) to convert the snippet of HTML code
that I had programmatically inserted in an output cell?

Comment: You are missing the display() closing brace. The edit button is greyed out for me

Comment: Thought I might have a solution but just testet it and you lose HTML formatting. So your Text gets printed but not in size h3. Here is a link to my answer in the tex forum in case no better answer comes up https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349818/123523

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this github issue](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/474) (which is still open at the time of writing) the PDF export goes through Latex which makes it hard to include HTML. Only trivial HTML works. In my experience not even markdown tables work well.

My workaround now was: File>DownloadAs>HTML, open the downloaded html with Chrome browser and say print. Select Destination "Save as PDF".

Comment: It looks like is not posible until now. HTML and webPDF work but it looses table of contents, code and wide tables are crop instead of collapse.