# jupyterlab pandas dataframe not save to PDF tables with html

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

When I added HTML to pandas dataframe in jupyterlab notebook[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqZS3.png) and try to export it to PDF[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LwC5.png) table is not exported, instead it shows

```
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
```

See bellow the notebook and PDF exported.

How can I solve this issue?

Notebook
[image: notebook]

PDF
[image: PDF]

Comment: This is because nbconvert converts to pdf via latex. You'll either need to export to webPDF or use the workaround suggested here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43965823/convert-notebook-generated-html-snippet-to-latex-and-pdf

Comment: webPDF it is very limited. Table of Contents are not exported, code and wide tables are crop (loose information) instead of collapse it.